# Dockerized React App failed to bind to $PORT on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, heroku, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Dockerized React App to Heroku, but keep getting the

> "R10: Failed to bind to $PORT error on Heroku"

.

The dockerized app runs perfectly fine when i docker run it locally.

My docker file looks like the following:

```
FROM node:10.15.3
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --verbose
RUN npm install serve -g -silent

# start app
RUN npm run build
CMD ["serve", "-l", "tcp://0.0.0.0:${PORT}", "-s", "/app/build"]
```

I followed the online solution to change the "listening" port on serve to $PORT from Heroku. Now the application is served on Heroku's port according to logs, but still, get the

> "Failed to bind to $PORT error"

.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable substitution does not happen in CMD that is why `${PORT}` is consider as a text instead of consuming its value.

Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, `CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ]` will not do variable substitution on `$HOME`. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]`. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker.

[docker-cmd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Change CMD to

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "serve -l tcp://0.0.0.0:${PORT} -s /app/build"]
```